# Folland's proof of the Hahn Decomposition. Minor error?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Theorem 3.3 of Folland's *Real Analysis* (ed 2) is the Hahn decomposition theorem. In the proof he assumes that the signed measure $\nu$ he is considering does not take the value $-\infty$. Then he argues:

> Let $m$ be the supremum of $\nu(E)$ as $E$ ranges over all positive
>   sets; thus there is a sequence $\{P_j\}$ of positive sets such that
>   $\nu(P_j) \to m$. Let $P = \cup_1^\infty P_j$. By Lemma 3.2 and
>   Proposition 3.1, $P$ is positive and $\nu(P)=m$; **in particular, $m < \infty.$**

The justification for the claim that $m<\infty$ is not clear to me. Could it be the case that Folland wanted to assume that $\nu$ does not take on the value $\infty$ in which case I think that the rest of the proof would work. Or am I missing something?

Comment: See the first line of the proof followed by the parenthetical remark. It also explains why $-\infty$ is not an issue. Keep in mind the definition of a signed measure.

Comment: Thanks. I have now looked at my library's copy of the book and there is indeed a sign error in an earlier printing. The excluded value is $\infty$

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are right. Folland did give an [errata](http://www.math.washington.edu/~folland/Homepage/oldreals.pdf) for his book which shows that $-\infty$ is a typo in the proof and it should be $+\infty$ instead.